# Jquery mobile offline viewing

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, offline-browsing

I have create a website using jquery mobile, and it works fantastic, now for the admin section, i want to build an offline page, wherein administrator can save data offline, and when he gets online, there would be a button saying, "Sync to the server" which would sync the content stored offline to online database.

I know it would be possible if i have native app, but as i currently have jquery mobile webapp, i want to build some solution with that, i tried researching on it, but every option suggested the native app way of doing this.

Is there any way i could achieve this on webapp and communicating with database within webapp?

Answer (score 0):

Why not try HTML5 application cache

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html manifest="demo.appcache">

    <body>
    The content of the document......
    </body>

    </html>
```

[read more here](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_app_cache.asp)

Comment: I tried above, i had a mobile webapp hosted on my machine and accessible to mobile using LAN, i created a manifest file listing all the of the required JS/CSS/Images, i ran the site on my mobile, after successful run i disconnected WIFI/Data and tried to access the same url, however it says You are Offline, i am using Chrome on mobile.